# on_member_update is creating multiple roles of one game even if role exists

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

[image: server roles]

For some reason the bot keeps making new 'Valorant' roles and it's only for 'Valorant'.
creating even if it exists.

```
@client.event
async def on_member_update(before, after):
    game_before = [i for i in before.activities if str(i.type) == "ActivityType.playing"]
    game_after = [i for i in after.activities if str(i.type) == "ActivityType.playing"]
    
    try:
        if game_after:
            game_name = game_after[0].name
            role = discord.utils.get(after.guild.roles, name=game_name)
            if role == None:
                r = random.randint(0,255)
                g = random.randint(0,255)
                b = random.randint(0,255)
                await after.guild.create_role(name=game_name, hoist=True, mentionable=True, colour=discord.Colour.from_rgb(r,g,b))
                role = discord.utils.get(after.guild.roles, name=game_name)
            await after.add_roles(role)
          
        elif game_before and not game_after:
            game_name = game_before[0].name
            role = discord.utils.get(after.guild.roles, name=game_name)
            if role in before.roles: 
                await after.remove_roles(role)
                
    except AttributeError:
        print('oops')
```

Comment: Is `VALORANT` the `game_name`?

Comment: You always call `after.add_roles(role)` if `game_after` is truthy. Wouldn't that cause the issue?

Comment: @blueteeth yes.

Comment: `after.add_role(role)` gives member the role but doesnt create it

Comment: You should always us `is None` instead of `== None` btw, but I don't think that's the issue. You're sure that the first instance of `role = discord.utils.get(after.guild.roles, name=game_name)`  is returning something? I would add logging after that to check what it is. In fact add logging everywhere.

Comment: Have you tried debugging/printing the variables `game_after`, `before`, `after`, `game_name`, and `after.guild` ? What is the result?

Answer (score 0):

This might not be correct but I haven't been able to test the solution.

My hypothesis is that the game_name contains a space at the end, and as I was able to test, you cannot create a role that terminates with a space (the space at the end will be removed).

Therefore when checking if the role with name "Valorant " for example, is in the list of roles, the answer will be no. The solution would be to [strip](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_strip.asp) the game_name before creating or searching the role. Your code will then be

```
@client.event
async def on_member_update(before, after):
    game_before = [i for i in before.activities if str(i.type) == "ActivityType.playing"]
    game_after = [i for i in after.activities if str(i.type) == "ActivityType.playing"]
    
    try:
        if game_after:
            game_name = game_after[0].name.strip()  # I just added the .strip()
            role = discord.utils.get(after.guild.roles, name=game_name)
            if role == None:
                r = random.randint(0,255)
                g = random.randint(0,255)
                b = random.randint(0,255)
                await after.guild.create_role(name=game_name, hoist=True, mentionable=True, colour=discord.Colour.from_rgb(r,g,b))
                role = discord.utils.get(after.guild.roles, name=game_name)
            await after.add_roles(role)
          
        elif game_before and not game_after:
            game_name = game_before[0].name
            role = discord.utils.get(after.guild.roles, name=game_name)
            if role in before.roles: 
                await after.remove_roles(role)
                
    except AttributeError:
        print('oops')
```

Don't hesitate to comment if it isn't clear or if this didn't work

Comment: I dont think this is it. I tried `game_name = game_after[0].name` and `print(f"'{game_name}'")` right after, and it printed `'VALORANT'` without a space at the end

Comment: I'm still trying to figure this out, do you have any other ideas?

Comment: No I don't know, it is pretty weird and it should work correctly. The fact it only has problems with Valorant indicates a problem in that special game_activity, and not your code I guess. 
If the problem is minor, you could find it by printing/debugging all the variables in the execution of the program, otherwise it might be an API bug, who knows :/